# Juniper SRX 1400: Policy to redirect users to custom URL

Tags: firewall, juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx, srx

## What I need

I have SRX 1400 @ JUNOS 12.3X48-D40.5

Imagine having, among others, following zones: `UNTRUSTED-CLIENTS`, `WORLD` and `INTRANET`.

I want to block all traffic from `UNTRUSTED-CLIENTS` to `WORLD`, but I want to keep users to know why they are being blocked, thus I want them to be redirected to custom URL (eg. `http://lockmessage.local`) on a machine located in `INTRANET`.

## Attempt

I have created a simple Application Firewall profile, that should match all traffic and deny it with `custom-redirect-url` specified. This profile has then been attached to a permit policy.

## Result

- The policy is correctly matched against traffic (as evidenced in logs)
- User cannot access any URL in `WORLD` zone, but...
- User does NOT reach a designated URL, getting timeouted instead :(
- No traffic between `UNTRUSTED-USERS` and `INTRANET` is logged

## Any suggestions?

- Should this work, or am I completely wrong?
- What might be missing?
- Is there another way I can achieve what I want?

## Config

Application firewall:

```
application-firewall {
    profile Block-Message-profile {
        block-message {
            type {
                custom-redirect-url {
                    content http://blockmessage.local;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    rule-sets Block-Message {
        rule Dummy-Policy-Deny-Everything {  # I am using any application available, since I need at least one rule;
            match {
                dynamic-application junos:GOOGLE;
                ssl-encryption any;
            }
            then {
                deny {
                    block-message;
                }
            }
        }
        default-rule {  # For all other websites - also block
            deny {
                block-message;
            }
        }
        profile Block-Message-profile;
    }
}
```

Afterwards, policy (ommited logging to make it tidy):

```
policies {
    from-zone UNTRUSTED-CLIENTS to-zone WORLD {
        policy REDIRECT-UNTRUSTED-CLIENTS-TO-BLOCK-URL {
            match {
                source-address any;
                destination-address any;
                application [ junos-http junos-https ];
            }
            then {
                permit {
                    application-services {
                        application-firewall {
                            rule-set Block-Message;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    from-zone UNTRUSTED-CLIENTS to-zone INTRANET {
        policy ALLOW-ACCESS-TO-BLOCK-URL-SERVER {
            match {
                source-address any;
                destination-address BOCK-URL-SERVER;
                application [ junos-http junos-https ];
            }
            then {
                permit 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Update 1

I've pinpointed a specific behavior that might give a clue.

When monitoring the `run show security application-firewall rule-set all` command output, I've noticed that:

1. the number of `sessions redirected` is always zero, so it's not the redirection failing to work, but rather failing to trigger;
2. the number of `sessions matched` is stuck at some old value of `85`, but does not grow anymore; this is most likely because I have limited the parent rule to `application junos-http`; the `85` value might mean, that in past, before limiting policy to `junos-ssh`, some other protocols might have matched/triggered the `default rule` but are no longer matching it; why?
3. the only counter that is visibly reacting to my traffic is `Number of sessions with appid pending`;
4. all these sessions are correctly matching the policy in question, it can be prooved with use of `show security flow session application-firewall-rule-set Block-Message`.

Full listing of command:

```
Rule-set: Block-Message
    Logical system: root-logical-system
    Profile: Block-Message-LAN-Unauthenticated-profile
    Rule: Dummy-Policy-Deny-Something
        Dynamic Application Groups: junos:web
        SSL-Encryption: no
        Action:reject or redirect
        Number of sessions matched: 0
        Number of sessions redirected: 0
Default rule:reject or redirect
        Number of sessions matched: 85
        Number of sessions redirected: 0
Number of sessions with appid pending: 4
```

Comment: Are you sure the untrusted client and/or the SRX can resolve the DNS of the redirect URL?

Comment: Yes, completely.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: No answer did help me so far, but I am still working on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is: you applied **a wrong profile** (`profile Block-Message-WLAN-profile`) on your `rule-sets Block-Message`.

The correct profile is `profile Block-Message-profile` (without 'WLAN' word in betwwen) as defined.

In addition, to ensure your `from-zone UNTRUSTED-CLIENTS to-zone INTRANET` policy is working properly, try to access/open the URL of blockmessage.local (on BOCK-URL-SERVER) directly from your untrusted clients.

I hope it is helpful.

Comment: I have applied a correct profile, I've just made this mistake while pasting and anonymising the code. This wouldn't be possible anyways, because misnamed and thus undefined profile, even if allowed during edit, would pop out during commit check :)

Comment: The second policy (``to-zone INTRANET``) works properly, I am able to access the blockmessage.local directly.

Comment: @MichałSacharewicz Does it work with http pages? please give it a try with http traffic and remove `ssl-encryption any`

Comment: I've tried it with both HTTP and HTTPS on the client side. As for redirection URL, it's HTTP, but the target server redirects client further to HTTPS on the same server.

Comment: @MichałSacharewicz  I meant you should try to with another simple http page in your rule-sets, do not use `junos:GOOGLE` with `ssl-encryption any`;

Comment: I have tried it with different apps. Also, several different URLs, most of which should fall into ``default-rule`` anyways.

Comment: @MichałSacharewicz hmmm... I am curious whether `block-message
type custom-text` works for you? Also, I am wondering why the page `http://blockmessage.local` is hosted on a machine in INTRANET? should SXR device host the page itself?

Comment: The ``custom-text`` option does not work either. But I've made some discovery - please see **Update 1** in the original post.